# Play 2.4: Form: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am new to Play framework and tried to mimic the **helloworld** sample in my local machine but I encountered an error:

[image]

**routes:**

```
# Home page
GET        /                    controllers.Application.index

# Hello action
GET        /hello               controllers.Application.sayHello


# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

**controller:**

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

import views._

class Application extends Controller {

  val helloForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "repeat" -> number(min = 1, max = 100),
      "color" -> optional(text)
    )
  )

  def index = Action {
    Ok(html.index(helloForm))
  }

  def sayHello = Action { implicit request =>
      helloForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.index(formWithErrors)),
      {case (name, repeat, color) => Ok(html.hello(name, repeat.toInt, color))}
    )
  }
}
```

**view:**

```
@(helloForm: Form[(String,Int,Option[String])])

@import helper._

@main(title = "The 'helloworld' application") { 
    <h1>Configure your 'Hello world':</h1> 
    @form(action = routes.Application.sayHello, args = 'id -> "helloform") {
        @inputText(
            field = helloForm("name"),
            args = '_label -> "What's your name?", 'placeholder -> "World"
        )

        @inputText(
            field = helloForm("repeat"),
            args = '_label -> "How many times?", 'size -> 3, 'placeholder -> 10
        ) 
        @select(
            field = helloForm("color"),
            options = options(
                "" -> "Default",
                "red" -> "Red",
                "green" -> "Green",
                "blue" -> "Blue"
            ),
            args = '_label -> "Choose a color"
        ) 
        <p class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="submit">
        <p> 
    } 
}
```

I have Play 2.4 installed and created the project using IntelliJ Idea 14 via **activator** template.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

After adding `implicit messages` parameters to views you can just add the following imports and use the old controller classes or even objects without any additional changes:

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
```

Comment: Why is this not the documentation's recommended approach? This seems so much simpler than extending `I18Support` and injecting the `MessagesApi`

Comment: I suppose that Play Framework developers try to popularize the new approach which is more customisable. Importing the `play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._` values introduces a hard-coded dependency on Play messaging provider. The dependency is not parameterized which is not convenient in some situations, e.g. for writing isolated unit tests. Thus the approach that uses controller classes with parameterized dependencies is more clean. Nevertheless, in my applications it is usually sufficient to use the oldschool controller *objects* with hardcoded dependencies. I prefer to use simpler solutions.

Comment: It's probably worth to mention that this approach is going to be deprecated with the removal of play's global state. See [Migration Guide / Dependency Injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Dependency-Injection).

Comment: Thank you! This is a good reason to move to the new approach.

Answer (score 44):

Using view form helpers (such as `@inputText`) requires you to pass an implicit `play.api.i18n.Messages` parameter to your view. You can do this adding `(implicit messages: Messages)` to the signature in your view. Your view becomes this:

```
@(helloForm: Form[(String,Int,Option[String])])(implicit messages: Messages)

@import helper._

@main(title = "The 'helloworld' application") { 
  <h1>Configure your 'Hello world':</h1> 
  ...
```

Then in your application controller you must make this parameter implicitly available in your scope. The simplest way to do this is to implement play's `I18nSupport` trait.

In your example, this would look like this:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport
import play.api.i18n.MessagesApi

import views._

class Application @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  val helloForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "repeat" -> number(min = 1, max = 100),
      "color" -> optional(text)
    )
  )

  def index = Action {
    Ok(html.index(helloForm))
  }

  def sayHello = Action { implicit request =>
    helloForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.index(formWithErrors)),
      {case (name, repeat, color) => Ok(html.hello(name, repeat.toInt, color))}
    )
  }
}
```

In your controller you can of course use your own implementation of `MessagesApi`. Since play knows out of the box how to inject a `MessagesApi` you can simply annotate your controller with `@Inject` and let play do the work for you.

As Matthias Braun mentioned, you also have to set

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

in your `build.sbt`

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N for more information about I18n.

Comment: you save my day! How can we disable of I18nSupport to avoid **(implicit messages: Messages)** in my  views?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to disable i18n support using forms. The only way I can think of would be to write your own form helpers without i18n support. See https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.package. But I don't think this is worth the effort.

Comment: When I do this, I get a "Controller needs to be abstract, since method messagesApi in trait I18nSupport of type => play.api.i18n.MessagesApi is not defined". Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: @MichaelA. you have to implement `messagesApi` in your controller. Either you do it your own by overriding `messagesApi` or you let Play do the work for you by simply injecting a `MessagesApi`. See the `@Inject` annotation in my answer.

Comment: I already have: `class AppController @Inject() (val messages: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport { ... }`. If I understood the answer correctly, that should be enough - but I still get that message.

Comment: @MichaelA. Change `val messages: MessagesApi` to `val messagesApi: MessagesApi`. This will automatically override `abstract def messagesApi` defined in `I18nSupport`.

Comment: Doh. Works now - a thousand thanks. One of those type of errors one can spend hours staring at...

Comment: To get this to work, I had to add `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator` to my `build.sbt` and prefix the routes to my controllers with `@`: `GET /hello @controllers.Application.sayHello`.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasBraun for pointing this out. Indeed the method described above requires dependency injected routing. However, including `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator` in `build.sbt` should be enough. Prefixing routes with `@` is not needed. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting#Dependency-Injection for details.

Comment: I also had to add `import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport` and `import play.api.i18n.MessagesApi` to get it to work.

Comment: I had to add (implicit messagesProvider: MessagesProvider), rather than (implicit messages: Messages), to get mine to work

Answer (score 1):

Using form helpers requires you to pass an implicit `play.api.i18n.Messages` parameter to your view. You can do this adding `(implicit messages: Messages)` to  in your view. Your view becomes this:

```
@(contacts: List[models.Contact], 
  form: Form[models.Contact])(implicit messages: Messages)
```

Then manually inject into your controllers

```
import play.api.data.Forms._

import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport

import play.api.i18n.MessagesApi
```

then finally add on to your main index controller class

```
class Application @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends
                                           Controller with I18nSupport {
```

Comment: This answer mostly copies parts of previous answers to the question!