# Implicit messages Scala Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to follow this:

[ToDoList Tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTodoList)

Basic tutorial to learn about the Play framework. I receive an error message on this line:

```
@inputText(taskForm("label"))
```

Where the error message is this:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
```

I render this view in my controller like this:

```
def tasks = Action {
   Ok(views.html.index(Task.all(), taskForm))
}
```

I've Googled the error message and it seems the implicit message is for internationalizing strings, but I've yet to find a post on how to actually fix this error and I'm also confused because this is an official tutorial, and the code doesn't compile.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799988/play-2-4-form-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-messages-play-api-i/30800825#30800825

Answer (score 2):

Try using an `implicit request` in the `Action`, and put an `implicit lang` at the top of the template.

```
def tasks = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.index(Task.all(), taskForm))
}
```

And at the top of the index template:

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[String])(implicit lang: Lang)
```

The `request` provides the `Lang` for the template.

Comment: This did not affect the error message when I tried to walk through this tutorial. I have the same error - of course the tutorial was for play 2.0 and now when you install you get 2.4

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had the same problem trying to go through the tutorial with Play 2.6.x, and resolved it by following the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800825/1033203, except that instead of using:

```
(implicit messages: Messages)
```

in my view signature, I needed:

```
(implicit messagesProvider: MessagesProvider)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass implicit request in the action and implicit play.api.i18n.Messages in the template.

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[String])(implicit messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)
```