# Play 2.4.4 I18N is not working?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
    - not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit handler: views.html.helper.FieldConstructor, 
     implicit messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class input. 
     Unspecified value parameter messages.
```

Here is my html code:

```
@phoneField(field: Field, className: String = "phone") = {
    @input(field, '_label -> "Phone numbers", '_class -> className) { (id, name, value, _) =>
        <input type="text" name="@name" value="@value"> 
        <a class="removePhone btn danger">Remove</a>
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, add the `@(...)(implicit messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)` to your view. Add more code for view and its controller.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaI18N).

Comment: The title of your post would suggest there was an issue with the framework, while the error seems quite clear and well-documented (appears like you neither know scala nor did you lookup on google). Also, if you (think you) face issues with a particular version of software, updating to the latest might help (2.4.6 in your case).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play 2.4: Form: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799988/play-2-4-form-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-messages-play-api-i)