# Using play.i18n.Lang or play.api.i18n.Messages at Play framework with Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I am trying to put internationalization on my Play for Scala example. I am following the book Play for Scala. I am getting errors about which parameter long use (`play.i18n.Lang` or `play.api.i18n.Messages`). The problem is that when I use `play.api.i18n.Messages` the method `@Messages("products.form")` and I have to use `@Messages.get("products.form")` from `play.i18n.Lang`. The errors are:

```
[info] Compiling 21 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/felipe/workspace-play/products/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/felipe/workspace-play/products/app/controllers/Products.scala:34: could not find implicit value for parameter lang: play.i18n.Lang
[error]       Ok(views.html.products.details(product))
[error]                                     ^
[error] /home/felipe/workspace-play/products/app/views/products/editProduct.scala.html:13: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
[error]      @helper.inputText(productForm("ean"))
[error]                       ^
[error] /home/felipe/workspace-play/products/app/views/products/editProduct.scala.html:14: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
[error]      @helper.inputText(productForm("name"))
[error]                       ^
[error] /home/felipe/workspace-play/products/app/views/products/editProduct.scala.html:15: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
[error]      @helper.textarea(productForm("description"))
[error]                      ^
[error] /home/felipe/workspace-play/products/app/views/products/list.scala.html:4: could not find implicit value for parameter lang: play.i18n.Lang
[error] @main(Messages.get("application.name")) {
[error]                                         ^
[error] 5 errors found
```

My controller :

```
package controllers

import models.Product
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{mapping, longNumber, nonEmptyText}
import play.api.mvc.Flash
import play.i18n._
// import play.api.i18n.Messages
// import play.api.Play.current
// import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._

/**
  * Created by felipe on 6/4/16.
  */
class Products extends Controller {

  private val productForm: Form[Product] = Form(
    mapping(
      "ean" -> longNumber.verifying(
        "validation.ean.duplicate", Product.findByEan(_).isEmpty),
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "description" -> nonEmptyText
    )(Product.apply)(Product.unapply)
  )

  def list = Action { implicit request =>
    val products = Product.findAll
    Ok(views.html.products.list(products))
  }

  def show(ean: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
    Product.findByEan(ean).map { product =>
      Ok(views.html.products.details(product))
    }.getOrElse(NotFound)
  }

  def save = Action { implicit request =>

    val newProductForm = productForm.bindFromRequest()

    newProductForm.fold(
      hasErrors = { form =>
        Redirect(routes.Products.newProduct()).
          flashing(Flash(form.data) +
            ("error" -> Messages.get("validation.errors")))
      },
      success = { newProduct =>
        Product.add(newProduct)
        val message = Messages.get("products.new.success", newProduct.name)
        Redirect(routes.Products.show(newProduct.ean)).flashing("success" -> message)
      }
    )
  }

  def newProduct = Action { implicit request =>
    val form = if (request.flash.get("error").isDefined)
      productForm.bind(request.flash.data)
    else
      productForm
    Ok(views.html.products.editProduct(form))
  }
}
```

My view:

```
@(productForm: Form[Product])(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)
@import play.i18n._
@import helper._

@main(Messages.get("products.form")) {
  <h2>@Messages.get("products.form")</h2>

  @helper.form(action = routes.Products.save()) {
    <fieldset>
     <legend>
      @Messages.get("products.details", Messages.get("products.new"))
     </legend>
     @helper.inputText(productForm("ean"))
     @helper.inputText(productForm("name"))
     @helper.textarea(productForm("description"))
    </fieldset>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value='@Messages.get("products.new.submit")'>
    </p>
   }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: activator-dist-1.3.10 - play 2.5.3 and scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work! Thanks anyway. Here is my solution based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799988/play-2-4-form-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-messages-play-api-i).

I am using view form helpers (such as `@inputText`) requires you to pass an `implicit play.api.i18n.Messages` parameter to your view. You can do this adding (`implicit messages: Messages`) to the signature. Then I am using application controller with this parameter implicitly available in my scope. The simplest way to do this is to implement play's `I18nSupport` trait.

```java
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject

import models.Product
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{longNumber, mapping, nonEmptyText}
import play.api.i18n.{I18nSupport, Messages, MessagesApi}
import play.api.mvc.Flash

/**
  * Created by felipe on 6/4/16.
  */
class Products @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  private val productForm: Form[Product] = Form(
    mapping(
      "ean" -> longNumber.verifying(
        "validation.ean.duplicate", Product.findByEan(_).isEmpty),
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "description" -> nonEmptyText
    )(Product.apply)(Product.unapply)
  )

  def list = Action { implicit request =>
    val products = Product.findAll
    Ok(views.html.products.list(products))
  }

  def show(ean: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
    Product.findByEan(ean).map { product =>
      Ok(views.html.products.details(product))
    }.getOrElse(NotFound)
  }

  def save = Action { implicit request =>

    val newProductForm = productForm.bindFromRequest()

    newProductForm.fold(
      hasErrors = { form =>
        Redirect(routes.Products.newProduct()).
          flashing(Flash(form.data) +
            ("error" -> Messages("validation.errors")))
      },
      success = { newProduct =>
        Product.add(newProduct)
        val message = Messages("products.new.success", newProduct.name)
        Redirect(routes.Products.show(newProduct.ean)).flashing("success" -> message)
      }
    )
  }

  def newProduct = Action { implicit request =>
    val form = if (request.flash.get("error").isDefined)
      productForm.bind(request.flash.data)
    else
      productForm
    Ok(views.html.products.editProduct(form))
  }
}
```

The view:

```
@(productForm: Form[Product])(implicit flash: Flash, messages: Messages)
@import helper._

@main(Messages("products.form")) {
  <h2>@Messages("products.form")</h2>

  @helper.form(action = routes.Products.save()) {
    <fieldset>
     <legend>
      @Messages("products.details", Messages("products.new"))
     </legend>
     @helper.inputText(productForm("ean"))
     @helper.inputText(productForm("name"))
     @helper.textarea(productForm("description"))
    </fieldset>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value='@Messages("products.new.submit")'>
    </p>
   }
}
```

Comment: did you try to get this sample working in playframework 2.6.x? If yes, could you please post an update for 2.6. I am having the same issue but I cannot get it to work. I don't understand what's wrong - it doesn't seem to solve the implicits properly.

Comment: I figured it out. Same as you did, the controller has `with I18nSupport` then the html templates have `(implicit messagesProvider: MessagesProvider)` and a simple action uses `implicit request =>`. It was painful!