# could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following piece of code

```
import play.api.i18n.{MessagesApi, Messages, I18nSupport}
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class HttpMessage(key: String, message: String)

object HttpMessage {
  implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[HttpMessage]

  def apply(key: String): HttpMessage = {
    HttpMessage(key, Messages(key))
  }
}
```

When compiled, it throws

```
[error] could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
[error]     HttpMessage(key, messages(key))
[error]                              ^
```

I made some research and it seems that it cannot find an `implicit` value for `MessagesAPI`. It seems it must be inject like in controllers but I do not know how because I am facing an `object` and `case class` here. `@Inject` annotation is not accepted.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could mark your object @Singleton and inject it where you need.

Comment: Or try to import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._

Comment: I already tried to import. Not working.

Comment: @insan-e How can I inject in `@Singleton` ?

Comment: You also need implicit application in scope for Messages implicits, so `import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._`, it should work, but Play.current approach is deprecated.

Comment: You can inject singleton the same way as "regular" class. The only difference is that the Guice(or whatever) will create only one instance of it. :)

Comment: Can't figure it out. Play is not allowing me to add `@Inject`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116609/discussion-between-insan-e-and-tzortzik).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30843682/4496364 :

`import play.api.Play.current
 import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._`

The first line is deprecated since Play now uses DI everywhere possible.

My approach (can't say if good or bad):

```
case class HttpMessage(key: String, message: String)

object HttpMessage {
  implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[HttpMessage]

  def apply(key: String)(implicit messages: Messages): HttpMessage = {
    HttpMessage(key, Messages(key))
  }
}
```

I had to create similar solution, so I used the implicit way, which Play uses also in it's templates. You must have `implicit request` in your controller for this to work. Also, in all service-like classes you need to forward this `implicit messages: Messages`...

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It seems to work without those two imports. Everything needed was `implicit messages: Messages`. Probably the imports are needed in other cases but I already have it imported in my controllers.