# Play 2.5: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I followed all the answers as provided in various links on this topic:

[Play 2.4: Form: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799988/play-2-4-form-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-messages-play-api-i)

[could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231814/could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-messages-play-api-i18n-messages?rq=1)

Yet, I am not able to get pass this error:

```
app/views/user.scala.html:4: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages

[error]   @helper.inputText(userForm("name"))
[error]                    ^
[error] app/views/user.scala.html:5: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
[error]   @helper.inputText(userForm("age"))
```

I am following the example from here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms

Comment: Please show us the content of `user.scala.html` and of your controller

Comment: As indicated in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaI18N) "You should add a Messages implicit parameter to your template like this: `@()(implicit messages: Messages)`"

Comment: Posted the contents as below.

Answer (score 0):

## user.scala.html:

```
@(userForm: Form[UserData]) (implicit messages: Messages)

@helper.form(action = routes.UserController.userPost()) {
  @helper.inputText(userForm("name"))
  @helper.inputText(userForm("age"))
}
```

## UserController.scala:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play.current

import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport
import play.api.i18n.MessagesApi
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._

import views._

case class UserData(name: String, age: Int)

class UserController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {
   val userForm = Form(
     mapping(
       "name" -> text,
       "age" -> number
     )(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply)
   )

   def index = Action {implicit request =>
     Ok(views.html.user(userForm))
   }
   def userPost = Action {implicit request =>
      userForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => {
          // binding failure, you retrieve the form containing errors:
          BadRequest(views.html.user(formWithErrors))
        },
        userData => {
         /* binding success, you get the actual value. */
         val name = userData.name
         val age = userData.age
         Ok(<message>Success !!</message>)
        }
      )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good, except perhaps the space between:

`@(userForm: Form[UserData]) (implicit messages: Messages)`

Try:

`@(userForm: Form[UserData])(implicit messages: Messages)`

Since it's supposed to be a grouped parameter

Comment: Oh my God ! That worked. Thanks a lot.
But it is so puzzling that space can cause a problem without giving any hints. And there is no documentation on this Play restriction.

Comment: Where to find such kind of syntax related restrictions in Play framework ? I believe it is a restriction of the Play and not of Scala.