# Implicit twirl parameter: Unspecified value parameter messages

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5, twirl

I am trying to use internationalization in twirl templates. I followed this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800825/1567737

I am having issues with the `implicit messages: Messages`. I have reduced my setup to the bare minimum on which the error occurs:

TestController

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.i18n.{I18nSupport, MessagesApi}
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

class TestController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) 
    extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.test.render())
  }

}
```

test.scala.html

```
@()(implicit messages: Messages)
```

I have also added `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator` to my build.sbt.

This should be sufficient according to the docs and the guide I linked above. Still I get the following compile time error:

```
[error] app/controllers/TestController.scala:11: not enough arguments for method render: (messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable.
[error] Unspecified value parameter messages.
[error]     Ok(views.html.test.render())
```

- Play Version: 2.5.9
- SBT version: 0.13.11
- Scala version: 2.11.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently implicit parameters only work on the `apply` method. And not when you explicitly call `render`.

`Ok(views.html.test.render())`

Must be

`Ok(views.html.test())`